# How to record internet radio?

Tags: rhythmbox, internet-radio

In 10.04 it was easy to display icecast streams; but whenever i click on the plugin nothing happens and no stream directory is loaded. The station recorder plugin seems to have disappeared also. If somenbody nows a fix thanx a lot.

Answer (score 5):

[**Streamtuner**](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/streamtuner)  + [**Streamripper**](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/streamripper):

or maybe

```
sudo apt-get install streamripper streamtuner
```

(I found a streamtuner2 in Synaptic too)

Run Streamtuner - There are a lot of radios  listed in there, search and just add them to bookmarks.

[image]

The music starts playing in external player (default player can be changed in Preferences). Recording automatically starts Streamripper - in terminal (by default, xterm).

Can only record mp3. **Gives specific name of music file as specified by the radio**.

Settings for custom folder for recorded files might not work, they go in home/user/name-of-radio.

Recording stops if xterm or Streamtuner is closed.

To add other stations that streamtuner might not know of - you can do that in Streamtuner - Stream - New Preselection. (See a possible problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/168818/47206).)

Answer (score 5):

StreamRipStar ([Download via Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stripper/)) is a convenient GUI for recording radio streams. I use it frequently.

Recording can be done time-delayed via built-in schedule manager, so you can record broadcasts while you are absent. (You may use an application like [Sentinella](http://sentinella.sourceforge.net/) for time-delayed shutdown of the system after recording has finished.)

Since it is in Java, you need to have Java runtime installed. This can be done via the Software Center: openjdk-7-jre.

It is run through Java:

`java -jar StreamRipStar<version_number>.jar`

Here are some screenshots.

Main window:

[image: Streamripstar (main window)]

Schedule manager:

[image: Streamripstar (schedule manager)]

"Add schedule job" dialogue:

[image: Streamripstar ("add schedule job" dialogue)]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the pre-installed app Sound Recorder while you are listening to your music station.

[image]

Comment: It records in very poor quality.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use vlc to record streams.

Comment: Can you expand this answer (by editing) to explain how?